Angular Loading time on menu click
When I click on the menu item it takes too much time to load
This is my app-routing-modules.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'login',
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'products',
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/products/products.module').then(m => m.ProductsModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'retailer-home',
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/retailer-home/retailer-home.module').then(m => m.RetailerHomeModule)
      },
   ]
  }
];

This is my product-routing-module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ProductsComponent } from './products.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ProductsComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class ProductsRoutingModule {}

First time when I clicked on the menu it took too much time to load.
This is Network tab


Since you are using lazy loading the js files are fetched only when the route is accessed, maybe that is the cause of the delay, one common way to speed up this, is to preload all the modules, so that as the website loads, the modules are preloaded in the background and may lessen this effect of waiting!
Preloading article
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule, PreloadAllModules} from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes, {
      preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules // <-changed here!
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}

